# ToSkip elements on C# circular list

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

I've to create an extension method `jump<T>` that, taken an arbitrary sequence s, returns an infinite sequence whose elements are obtained visiting in a circular way s and skipping n elements. So, if step == 0, then all the sequence is returned (infinite times), if step == 1, let's take all the numbers in the interval [0-10] as an example, will return 0,2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5 ecc. If step==2 then the result will be 0,3,6,9,1,4,7,10.
Obviously this is only an example with an ordered list of int, i need to do so with a generic sequence of T elements.

How can i achieve that?

To test it, i created a nunit test as following:

```
  [Test]
        public void Jumping_validArg_IsOk()
    {

        var start = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
            .Jumping(3)
            .ToList()//remove this to make it work
            .Take(4);
        var expected = new[] {1, 5, 9, 2};
       CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(start, expected);
    }
```

but it seems to never end and it throws a `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

**The solution:**
I modified a little what i selected as best answer to make it more general in this way:

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> Jump<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int step)
        {
            var pos = 0;
            var list = sequence.ToList();
            while (true)
            {
                yield return list[pos];
                pos = (pos + step + 1) % list.Count;
            }
        }
```

In this way it should work with all the IEnumerable. I added a comment on the test to show what to delete to make it work. I hope it's all correct.

Comment: You don't need the `ToList()`. And that's good because when used like this it will never return.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes you're right, it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this very easily with a [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) statement:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Jump<T>(this IList<T> data, int step) {
    int pos = 0;
    while(true) {
        yield return data[pos];
        pos = (pos + step) % data.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: An `IList<>` is not directly "an arbitrary sequence".

Comment: I tried that, but the test i just posted on my edited question doesn't even end. Maybe i wrote the test in a wrong way... And i modified your answer using 'data.ToList()[pos]' so that i can use an IEnumerable as argument.

Comment: @Sanci - Yes, it's hard to test something that's  'infinite'

Comment: @HenkHolterman i hoped using that '.Take(4)' could help to take only a portion to test

Comment: Try putting it before the ToList().

Comment: @Sanci using `data.ToList()[pos]` is a bad idea. Call `ToList()` before the loop and store result in local variable instead.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek thanks, i fixed it. I post my "new version" under the question.